# Difference between PrincipalSearcher.FindAll() and GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity()

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I am trying to get all the members of a local group from a remote hosts.
I found a way using the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace but I end up with inconsistencies...

- GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity returns a group object containing only
  local members of a group
- PrincipalSearcher.FindAll returns a group
  object containing all members of a group (Domain + Local)

Using **PrincipalSearcher.FindAll** (See bellow), I get all the members (Domain + Local) of a group.

Output:

- Member: Homer - S-1-5-21-4017887476-2895526723-3552248342-500
- Member: smithers - S-1-5-21-4017887476-2895526723-3552248342-1009
- Member: Domain Admins - S-1-5-21-452759756-260371901-2912106767-512
- Member: SomeAdminGroup - S-1-5-21-452759756-260371901-2912106767-1154
- Member: Smithers - S-1-5-21-452759756-260371901-2912106767-1124

Code:

```
 using (var machineContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, hostname))
 using (var gpSeach = new PrincipalSearcher(new GroupPrincipal(machineContext)))
 {
      foreach (GroupPrincipal gp in gpSeach.FindAll().Where(gp => gp.SamAccountName == "Administrators"))
      {
           foreach (var member in gp.Members)
           {
                Trace.WriteLine("Member: " + member.Name+ " - " + member.Sid);
           }
      }
  }
```

Using **GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity**, I only get the local members of a group:

Output:

- Member: Homer - S-1-5-21-4017887476-2895526723-3552248342-500
- Member: smithers - S-1-5-21-4017887476-2895526723-3552248342-1009

Code:

```
 using (var machineContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, hostname, null, ContextOptions.Negotiate, "myUsername", "myPassword"))
 using (GroupPrincipal localAdminGp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(machineContext, IdentityType.Name, "Administrators"))
 {
     foreach (var member in localAdminGp.Members)
     {
          Trace.WriteLine("Member: " + member.Name + " - " + member.Sid);
     }
 }
```

What is happening under the curtain to get those 2 different outcomes !?!